# How to find explain plan of a query through eclipse link

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g, eclipselink

I have a Java application with `JPA and eclipse link` as backend . I had like to find `explain plan` of a particular query that gets executed, while the application is running . I know i can check it through sql developer , but i would like to find the explain plan of the query when it is invoked by the application . Is there a way to do it?

I tried adding `explain plan for select 1 from dual` but it kept throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have many options. For some unknown reason both hibernate and enclipselink do not support something like that see [setting-context-in-a-jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045219/setting-context-in-a-jpa-connection-is-this-safe)

So you have to use pure Oracle solution

- Create `LOGON TRIGGER ON SCHEMA` and enable  session tracing in it. Run the app and analyze the trace file then
- Check content of the `v$SQL_PLAN` view and check the real exec plan for the query.

If you insist on doing it from Eclipse link then you must start transaction somehow, to avoid returning the session into the pool. Query `v$mystat` and `v$session` to get `SID`, `SERIAL#` (to get unique session identifier). Then execute your query. And get `SQL_ID` and `PREV_SQL_ID` from `v$session`. Check `v$sql_plan` and `v$sql_text` to get queries sql text and exec plan.